# Function returns int but getting strange behavior

Tags: c, function, printf, return-value

I wrote some code to count the bits in a word. When I `printf()` the count it prints 32 as expected but when I stuck the same code in a function and printed the return value it gives me some crazy large number.

I then copy/pasted the code back into `main()` printed the count and printed the return value of my function at the same time and hey both gave me 32 but if I then comment out the code in `main()` my function again prints the large number.

Anyone have an idea about why this is happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int wordlength();

int main() {

printf("%d", wordlength()); // prints 4195424 but
                          // if I uncomment the code below
                          // it then prints 32 like I want

//  int count;
//  unsigned int n = ~0;
// 
//  while( n != 0) {
//      n = n >> 1;
//      count++;
//  }
//  printf("\n%d", count); // prints 32 as expected

    return 0;
}

int wordlength() {

    int count;
    unsigned int n = ~0;

    while( n != 0) {
        n = n >> 1;
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: You could avoid all this by printing `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`

Comment: Using `-1` instead of `~0` means you code will work even on esoteric platforms

Comment: @M.M I don't believe there exists a system where `~0` wouldn't work for an unsigned int?

Comment: @M.M If you are going to worry about esoteric platforms: the OP's approach works correctly on platforms with padding bits, your multiplication does not.

Comment: @Lundin `~0u` is portable, but `(unsigned) ~0` only means the same thing when `~0` evaluates as `-1`, i.e. when two's complement is used for negative numbers.

Comment: @hvd Aah right, the literal 0 is of type `int` of course.

Comment: @hvd if we assume he wants to know the number of value bits, not the total number of bits in the word

Comment: @M.M If you propose the multiplication as a replacement for the OP's code, without warning that it does something different from the OP's code, I see that as a problem in your comment. But yes, it is possible that on such systems the OP's code doesn't return the desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `wordlength()` function, `count` is an automatic local scope variable and  is not initialized explicitly. So, the initial value is indeterminate.

To quote `C11` standard, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...]

You're readily applying post-increment onto it. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, annex §J.2, reasons for undefined behavior,

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate.

So, your program exhibits UB and not guaranteed to produce any valid result, at all.

Solution: Initialize `count` to 0.

FWIW, regarding the comment

> // if I uncomment the code below
>                             // it then prints 32 like I want

is also a result of UB.

Comment: Wow thanks, can't believe I missed that. Since the same code in main() works without being initialized to zero is it being auto initialized?

Comment: @ThusSpokeChris nopes, it's also UB.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize `count` to 0 or something, or it will have undefined value.